# How can docker communicate to other hosts in local network using hostnames?

Tags: linux, docker, dhcp, hostname

I have two computers in the same network with below hostnames and IP address(Dynamic IPs):

```
host1.local - 10.0.0.11
host2.local - 10.0.0.12
```

`host1` is running Docker with default configuration.

Containers in `host1` are able to connect to `host2` using the IP address `10.0.0.12` but are unable to connect to the `host2` using the hostname `host2.local`. Can anyone please let me know how can the containers directly connect to the `hosts2` using hostnames. Please note that both the servers `host1, host2` are in DHCP server and don't have fixed ip address so configuring the file **/etc/hosts** doesn't work in my case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Docker containers usually are in the [default bridge network](https://docs.docker.com/network/bridge/):

> When you start Docker, a default bridge network (also called bridge) is created automatically, and newly-started containers connect to it unless otherwise specified.

You can also have user-defined bridges with their own DNS service:

> User-defined bridges provide automatic DNS resolution between containers.
>
> On a user-defined bridge network, containers can resolve each other by name or alias.

There are additional options to configure DNS resolution in a container (see [here](https://docs.docker.com/config/containers/container-networking/)):

> By default, a container inherits the DNS settings of the host, as defined in the `/etc/resolv.conf` configuration file. Containers that use the default bridge network get a copy of this file, whereas containers that use a custom network use Docker’s embedded DNS server, which forwards external DNS lookups to the DNS servers configured on the host.
>
> Custom hosts defined in /etc/hosts are not inherited. To pass additional hosts into your container, refer to "add entries to container hosts file" in the docker run reference documentation. You can override these settings on a per-container basis.

And [add entries to container hosts file](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#add-entries-to-container-hosts-file---add-host) says:

> You can add other hosts into a container’s `/etc/hosts` file by using one or more `--add-host` flags. This example adds a static address for a host named docker:
>
> ```
> $ docker run --add-host=docker:93.184.216.34 --rm -it alpine
> ```

You can of course also configure the upstream DNS server to properly resolve `*.local`. If you use mDNS for that, the upstream DNS server must be able to use it.